# rsync SSH agent forwarding through 3 remote systems doesn't work with single command

Tags: ssh, rsync, gnome-keyring

I can do the following:

```
$local> ssh -A remote1
$remote1> rsync -e "ssh remote2 ssh " remote3:/file .
$remote1>
```

and this works because keys for both `remote1` and `remote2` are in my gnome keyring, and `remote3` doesn't require a password. However the following fails:

```
$local> ssh -A remote1 "./scriptOnRemote1.sh"
```

where `scriptOnRemote1.sh` performs the exact same rsync command. It produces the following errors:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib64/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

The difference between the verbose outputs of those two cases starts with

```
pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Afaik ssh agent is not forwarded for "commands", only for the shells.

Comment: Why not? I can't find indication of this in the man page.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because the script you are running does not access your key.  It should also not work if you did:

```
ssh -A remote1 'rsync -e "ssh remote2 ssh " remote3:/file .'
```

Comment: I would not be surprised if that were the case (I'll try). But this doesn't help. How can I make the command or script access my key from the forwarded agent?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible.  Here is a guess at something that might work:  $local> ssh -A remote1 "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK; ./scriptOnRemote1.sh"  (If your script has access to the agent socket, it might just magically work.)

Answer (score 1):

Please run `ssh-agent` after logon to remote1 host.